# import command in Java

Tags: java, import

What exactly is the difference between the following commands:

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
```

and

```
import javax.swing.*;
```

If I use second one, compiler will import all files from swing or only the needed ones, will be any difference in size of the executable? thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one imports only [`javax.swing.JPanel` class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html).

The second one imports all classes which are present in [`javax.swing` package](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html), excluding the classes in its subpackages, such as the ones in `javax.swing.event` package, etc.

The `import` keyword does not literally import the given classes. It basically just points the compiler to the classes which are to be present in the classpath in order to be able to locate the dependency classes and thus successfully compile the code. The size of the compiled class depends on the size of the sole source code (this includes the import statements), it does not include the size of the imported classes.

#### See also

- [Java tutorial - Using package members](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in terms of execution of your application. Only difference is during the compile time it may be a bit (unnoticeable in most cases) slower. A lot of people prefer the .* over fully qualified packages because of code readability.

I asked this question myself once too and I found this [explanation](http://www.javaperformancetuning.com/news/qotm031.shtml) to be pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in Java you don't produce executables (well, you can, but not directly). At run time, the JVM will load whatever is needed for the program to run from a library that is already on the disk, so your executable won't grow.

Having a catch-all import merely reduces the need to explicitly list everything you are importing. It's actually often discouraged because that could later create conflicts (e.g., what if you were already obtaining x.y.Foo and now there is also w.v.Foo in your w.f.* import).

Some IDEs (such as Eclipse) can fix the latter into the former for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The first one will import that specific package but the second one will import all packages in swing.  The first one will be smaller because it is only one package.

Answer (score 0):

for example, import java.lang.* will import all the classes that exist in package java.lang (but no subpackages). By all I mean any class we really use in project, nothing what is not required will be imported (so I was taught).